# Coloring a graph which is not quite complete.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let us assume we have a graph, such that given any $n$ vertices, there is an edge missing.  Can we $n$ color this graph?

An example where you can do this is the line graph of a complete graph.  The line graph of $K_4$ has $6$ vertices and given any $4$ of them, there is an edge missing.  And we can color the line graph with $4$ colors.  I'm just wondering if you can in general.

Comment: If it is not the case, it seems like we could put a lower bound on the number of vertices that a graph must have to violate this.  For example, maybe $nC2$, where the motivation from this comes from these line graph examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Grötzsch graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph) provides a counterexample. It is a triangle-free graph, but has chromatic number $4$, so for any $3$ vertices, there is an edge missing, but the graph is not $3$-colorable.

[image: Grötzsch graph]

Image from Wikipedia.

In general, by [a theorem of Mycielski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian), there exist triangle free graphs with arbitrarily large chromatic number, so it doesn't work just to increase the bound.

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I'm looking for.  Do you happen to know off hand if you can use a similar process to find the smallest that doesn't contain a clique of size $n$, but still requires more than $n$ colors to color.

Comment: I guess to clarify a bit, they say that this is the smallest triangle free graph with chromatic number 4.  I would think there couldn't be a smaller triangle free graph with higher chromatic number.  So in this case, we might expect that any triangle free graph with less than 11 vertices can be 3 colored.

Comment: @mow I'm afraid I don't know of any relevant generalizations - I am definitely not an expert in this field. And yes, that is what it implies - any triangle free graph with less than $11$ vertices is $3$-colorable.